# HTML5/CSS Image Rollover on BigCartel

Tags: css, html, image

I've been trying to create a image rollover with a link on my BigCartel account, which uses HTML5 and CSS.

My HTML:

```
<div id="icons">
{% if Show_Twitter_Icon == 'Yes' or if Show_Twitter_Icon == 'yes' %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ Your_Twitter_Url }} class=mysprite target="new"><img src="my url link" ></a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

My CSS:

```
#mysprite {
    display: block;
    background: url('my url link') no-repeat;
}

#mysprite:hover {
    background: url('my url link') no-repeat;
}
```

This is doing my head in, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class of `mysprite`, not an `id`, so it would at least have to be—

```
.mysprite {
    display: block;
    background: url('my url link') no-repeat;
}
.mysprite:hover {
    background: url('my url link') no-repeat;
}
```

Can't guarantee that's all that needs altering, but it's an essential start. :-)

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work :(, thanks though. Is there a problem if there are 2 div id's and then the class?

Comment: The point is, you have a class in the HTML but you are trying to target it in the CSS with an ID selector. You need to target it with a class selector (a dot). That's all. If it still doesn't work, then there are further issues to be addressed, but it can't work without fixing the selector issue. If it's still not working, post a full code example so that people can show you what to do next.